# Go build in docker container is way slower than on the root system

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to build a go package with the following command:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o bin/router -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w'
```

This takes around 0.5 seconds on my pc. The same command in a docker container takes 45 seconds.

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /app/router -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w' /build/src/global/router
```

Locally I have go version `1.12.9 linux/amd64`. The docker container uses the `golang:1.13` image as base.

My guess would be that the docker build process has less CPU available but does that make this big of a difference? What could be the cause for this issue?

This is reproducable with a minimal example:

`main.go`:

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Println("test")
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.13

ADD main.go .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w'

CMD [ "main" ]
```

The command inside the docker container takes about 5 seconds compared to < 0.1 seconds on my pc.

Comment: Does your application have library dependencies?  Does every `docker build` command need to download them, but your local build already has them cached?

Comment: I'm using go mod and all the dependencies are cached in a prior build step in the dockerfile.

Comment: You means that you has a docker build multistep? The problem is CGO_ENABLED, you machine is caching when Docker isn't.

Comment: I also tried running `go build -o /app/router /build/src/global/router` this makes it faster but it still takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem isn't build on container itself.

```
$ go clean
$ time GO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w'

real    0m0,233s
user    0m0,278s
sys 0m0,094s

$ time GO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w'

real    0m0,076s
user    0m0,098s
sys 0m0,053s

$ go clean
$ time GO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-w'

real    0m0,238s
user    0m0,315s
sys 0m0,070s
```

You can see the times that build takes after 'go clean' in comparation consecutives build.

> SYNOPSIS go clean [-i] [-r] [-n] [-x] [ packages ]
>
> DESCRIPTION Clean
>
> removes object files from package source directories. The go command
>   builds most objects in a temporary directory, so go clean is mainly
>   concerned with object files left by other tools or by manual
>   invocations of go build.

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/golang-go/go-clean.1.en.html

In each try to build on your computer are you clearing your build folder?

Comment: the problem of build on container is that the container doesn't keep state between each build.

Comment: I also think the problem is that the go cache directory is gone everytime the go build step is executed in the docker container

Comment: The question now is if there is a solution for this in docker. Can you somehow keep the build cache?

Comment: On my experience, if the problem were time of downloading external resources maybe yes. But I don't think that caching the build itself follows the docker filosofy. Anyway, I recommend you make a multi step docker file to separate the build of the run.